# How to port android to device on ARM9 processor?

Tags: android, linux, arm, arm9

I want to port Android on the device with ARM9 200Mhz and no-fpu support, Is this possible, Has google revealed all code of android or it is just available to partners?

```
if ANDROID_PORT_POSSIBLE
{
      Is there any tutorial available for porting? 
}
```

Thanks and Regards,

Sunny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article might help you

http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/Linux-For-Devices-Articles/Porting-Android-to-a-new-device/

Answer (score 1):

ARMv5TE is the minimum ([as said here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-internals/browse_thread/thread/0e5ec44398e03729/2f97e466ce034174)), and some ARM9 CPUs are ARMv4. As I know you are using ARM926, which is ARMv5TE, so it's possible.

You can search [google.groups](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agroups.google.com+android+arm926) - there is a lot of information. I think, you can find ready-for-compilation ARM9 sources.

Answer (score 1):

Someone tried making the ARMv5te code run on ARMv4t CPUs by emulating the missing instructions in the kernel. In the end they were defeated but the blog describing the efforts is a technical tour-de-force!
http://benno.id.au/blog/2007/11/21/android-neo1973

Meanwhile someone else has succeeded by recompiling everything for armv4: http://wiki.openmoko.org/wiki/User:Seanmcneil3